# Install PHP5 Via Macports Always Error

Tags: php, macos, macports

I want to install php5 on my mac using macports. It throws the following error on terminal:

> Attempting to fetch php5-5.3.12_0+apache2.darwin_11.x86_64.tbz2.rmd160 from http://packages.macports.org/php5
>   Error: org.macports.archivefetch for port php5 returned: Failed to verify signature for archive!
>   Please see the log file for port php5 for details:
>
> /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_lang_php5/php5/main.log
>   To report a bug, follow the instructions in the guide:
>      http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets
>   Error: Processing of port php5 failed

What should I do?

Comment: What's the command you are using to install it?